# Terminal Command to write mp3 info to text file

Tags: unix, terminal

I'm hoping to run a command that will get the info from mp3's in a directory and write each MP3's info to a text file with the same name.

Using id3lib to get the MP3 info. This is what I have so far but not working as expected.

This gives me a text file named "{}.txt" with the info

```
    find . -name \*.mp3 -exec info=$(id3info {}); name=({}); echo $info >> {}.txt
```

Working toward something like this

```
    find . -name \*.mp3 -exec info=$(id3info {}) : filename=$({}); echo $info >> $filename.text : restart ;\
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to execute a shell command as an argument to `-exec` option.  The following might work for you:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec sh -c "id3info {} > {}.txt" \;
```

If you also need the mp3 filename to be added to the output, say:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -exec sh -c "{ echo {} ; id3info {} ; } > {}.txt" \;
```

Comment: Great. Works as expected. Only thing is it the filename includes .mp3 like this; "test.mp3.txt"